# Merge three applications into one in asp.net mvc 3.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have three MVC3 web project into a single solution, like admin, UI and service(WCF service).

Now i need to merge it into a single project as i have to host it on a single IP on Network solution. Please suggest how we can combine all these project.

Answer (score 0):

You can host the three applications on a server and bind them with the same IP but different port number. In the application bindings give different port numbers to the applications. Like default (80) for UI and port 8080 for web-services and port 8090 for admin application.

Another option is to use the same IP and ports but ask your admin to configure 3 host name in DNS that map to the same IP. Then in bindings specific each distinct hostname for each of the web applications.

If the above solutions are not acceptable in your case then you need to make some changes to the application and organize it using MVC areas. Then you will have one application and 3 areas however you need to take care of session management, security,etc if they differ in the 3 apps. Here is info: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Another one: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/article.php/c20227/Using-Areas-in-ASPNET-MVC-Application.htm

Comment: Abhijit, Thanks for all solutions. I have already worked upon your 1st option,so it was not new to me ,and the problem is that i cant specify different ports at hosting area... Right now i am trying through areas (which is pretty good option) and your 2nd option i haven't tried yet.